# Changing a collectionView cell changes all of them

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

This is the code that gets the info from Firebase. It changes the cell's imageView image and the label's text. When it runs the code all of the cells have the same image and label text.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "suggestionCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SuggestionCollectionViewCell

    Database.database().reference().child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            let imageURL = dict["imageURL"] as! String
            let url = URL(string: imageURL)
            let username = dict["username"] as! String
            cell.imageView!.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
            cell.usernameLabel.text = username
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You should not be performing Firebase observations in `cellForItemAt`. You need to update your data model and when the model is updated, reload the associated item in the collection view.

Comment: for user in dataSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {}

Answer (score 2):

Actually for every cell rendering, you are fetching all the users from your Firebase database. Every call's last call is the user you are seeing multiple times. It overrides the previous ones.

To fix you problem you can store your users in an array.

```
var users = [User]()
```

To populate this array, you call a similar function like this in your viewDidLoad

```
func fetchUsers() {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                let user = User()
                //set user properties here
                users.append(user)
          }
      }
  }
```

When you fetched all the users, you should reload your collectionView

```
collectionView.reloadData()
```

In your cellForItemAt function you can now access the users

```
let user = users[indexPath.row]
```

Use the user variable to setup you cell

Answer (score -1):

To remove this problem, firstly you should gather all the data from the firebase in array and then use that array for table view accordingly.